# char type in va_arg

Tags: c, arguments

I have the following function which writes passed arguments to a binary file.

```
void writeFile(FILE *fp, const int numOfChars, ...)
{
   va_list ap;
   va_start(ap, numOfChars);
   for(int i = 0; i < numOfChars; i++)
   {
      const char c = va_arg(ap, char);
      putc(c, fp);
   }
   va_end(ap);
}
```

Upon compiling, I get the following warning from the compiler

```
 warning: second argument to 'va_arg' is of promotable type 'char'; this va_arg
      has undefined behavior because arguments will be promoted to 'int' [-    Wvarargs]
```

Now as I understand it, C wants to promote char type to int. Why does C want to do this? Second, is the best solution to cast the int back to a char?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Now as I understand it, C wants to promote char type to int. Why does C want to do this?

Because that's what the standard says. If you pass an integral value with conversion rank smaller than that of `int` (e. g. `char`, `bool` or `short`) to a function taking a variable number of arguments, it will be converted to `int`. Presumably the reason for this has its roots in performance, where it was (and in fact, often it still is nowadays) better to pass values aligned to a machine word boundary.

> Second, is the best solution to cast the int back to a char?

Yes, but you don't really need a cast even, an implicit conversion will do:

```
char ch = va_arg(ap, int);
```

Comment: Neither a cast or an implicit conversion is needed. See the end of my (updated) answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson What do you mean by that no implicit conversion is needed? Surely you can't write `char ch = va_arg(ap, char)` since it's undefined? If you want a `char` out of the argument list, you have to pass `int` to `va_arg`, is that not right?

Comment: What I mean is that the correct code would be `int c = va_arg(ap, int); putc(c, fp);`. You *could* make `c` a `char`, but since `putc()` takes an `int` argument there's not much point in doing so.

Comment: It's not *incorrect* (though it could have some problems). `va_arg(ap, int)` returns a result of type `int`, which is converted from `int` to `char` by the initialization of `ch`. If plain `char` is signed and the result exceeds `CHAR_MAX` (typically 127), then the result of the conversion is implementation-defined, though it will almost always undergo the usual 2's-complement wraparound. If `ch` is then passed to `putc`, that function itself will convert it to `unsigned char`; the result of that conversion is well defined.

Comment: But since `va_arg()` can't yield a `char`, and `putc` takes an `int` argument, you might as well use `int` consistently. (If the caller of `writeFile` happens to pass an argument that's outside the range of `unsigned char`, it will be converted by `putc`, which should normally give you the expected behavior.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Actually I was just confused about the wording "*the* correct code" – I'm aware of the implementation-defined behavior, and I agree that not relying on it is better than relying on it.

Comment: You're right, the word "correct" was an overstatement.

Answer (score 16):

Variadic functions are treated specially.

For a non-variadic function, the prototype (declaration) specifies the types of all the parameters. Parameters can be of any (non-array, non-function) type -- including types narrower than `int`.

For a variadic function, the compiler doesn't know the types of the parameters corresponding to the `, ...`. For historical reasons, and to make the compiler's job easier, any corresponding arguments of types narrower than `int` are promoted to `int` or to `unsigned int`, and any arguments of type `float` are promoted to `double`. (This is why `printf` uses the same format specifiers for either `float` or `double` arguments.)

So a variadic function *can't receive* arguments of type `char`. You can call such a function with a `char` argument, but it will be promoted to `int`.

(In early versions of C, before prototypes were introduced, *all* functions behaved this way. Even C11 permits non-prototype declarations, in which narrow arguments are promoted to `int`, `unsigned int`, or `double`. But given the existence of prototypes, there's really no reason to write code that depends on such promotions -- except for the special case of variadic functions.)

Because of that, there's no point in having `va_arg()` accept `char` as the type argument.

But the language doesn't *forbid* such an invocation of `va_arg()`<strike>; in fact the section of the standard describing `<stdarg.h>` doesn't mention argument promotion</strike>. The rule is stated in the section on function calls, [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.5.2.2 paragraph 7:

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
> does include a prototype, the arguments are implicitly converted, as
> if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking
> the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its
> declared type. The ellipsis notation in a function prototype
> declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last
> declared parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on
> trailing arguments.

And the description of the `va_arg()` macro, 7.16.1.1, says (emphasis added):

> If there is no actual next argument, or if type is not compatible with
> the type of the actual next argument (**as promoted according to the
> default argument promotions**), the behavior is undefined, except for
> the following cases:
> [SNIP]

The "default argument promotions" convert narrow arguments to `int`, `unsigned int`, or `double`. (An argument of an unsigned integer type whose maximum value exceeds `INT_MAX` will be promoted to `unsigned int`. It's theoretically possible for `char` to behave this way, but only in a very unusual implementation.)

> Second, is the best solution to cast the int back to a char?

No, not in this case. Casts are rarely necessary; in most cases, implicit conversions can do the same job. In this particular case:

```
const char c = va_arg(ap, char);
putc(c, fp);
```

the first argument to `putc` is already of type `int`, so this is better written as:

```
const int c = va_arg(ap, int);
putc(c, fp);
```

`putc` internally converts its `int` argument value to `unsigned char` and writes it to `fp`.

Comment: Thanks Keith. I keep learning new things about C every day. :)

Comment: "But the language doesn't _forbid_ [...]" -- I'm lost here. It's explicitly undefined: 7.16.1.1 (`va_arg`) p2 "[I]f _type_ is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the default argument promotions), the behavior is undefined, except for the following cases: [...]"

Comment: @mafso: *Undefined behavior* doesn't mean it's forbidden. `va_arg(ap, char)` is neither a syntax error nor a constraint violation; a conforming compiler is not required to reject or diagnose it.

Comment: I agree (I'm not even sure if a compiler is allowed to reject a program with an (unreached) `va_arg(ap, char)`, GCC warns that the program will abort if the code is reached), I was confused about "doesn't mention argument promotion". Anyway, I consider this answer useful with or without that part, even if I find it slightly misleading. (I would read "forbid" as "forbid for strictly conforming code", but maybe that's just me.)

Comment: @mafso: You were probably confused about "doesn't mention argument promotion" because that was wrong. I've just updated it.